# Discuss the convergence of the sequence $(a_{n})$, where $a_{n}:=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+ \dots +\frac{1}{n^2}$. How to show this

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Discuss the convergence of the sequence $(a_{n})$, where $a_{n}:=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+ \dots +\frac{1}{n^2}$?

Comment: Do you have any ideas? What tools do you have to analyse convergence of series?

Comment: I was trying to show that this sequence is Cauchy sequence. We can write this as \sum_{k=0}^{n}1/k^2 and use definition of Cauchy

Comment: Using Cauchy will be a little bit of a circle. Since for all $\epsilon >0$ you must find a $M$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k^2} - \sum_{k=0}^m\frac{1}{k^2} < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge m \ge M$. Taking $m=M$, and $n$ really big, you show $\sum_{k=M}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < \epsilon$, which is practically that same as showing $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < \infty$, for which you want to use Cauchy, so your back at square 1.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1{k^2}<\frac1{(k-1)k}=\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k$$ and by telescoping, the sum (but the term $k=1$) is bounded by $$1-\frac1n.$$

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Thanks for your interest in this answer. The telescopic sum avoids the recourse to an integral.

Answer (score 1):

Use cauchy condensation test, whic says $\Sigma a_{n}$ converges iff $\Sigma 2^{n}a_{2^{n}}$ converges. Thus $\Sigma \frac{1}{n^{2}}$ converges iff $\Sigma \frac{2^{n}}{2^{2n}}$ converges. ie, iff $\Sigma\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ converges. We know the latter series is a geometric series which converges to 2.

Comment: ($a_n$ positive decreasing) tks I didn't know this way for showing the convergence of Riemann integrals

Answer (score 0):

It's a p-series, and if p>1, it converges. No need to do anything more elaborate, the tags on this question are calculus and sequences/series, not analysis (not that the post below me is wrong, or anything, of course; and my apologies if the OP is doing this for a more advanced course. This explanation is perfect for calculus however).

Answer (score 0):

By approximating the sum by a definite integral from above,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}=1+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k^2}\int_{k-1}^k\mathrm dx\le1+\int_1^n\frac1{x^2}\mathrm dx=1+[-x^{-1}]_1^n=2-\frac1n.
$$
The sequence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}
$$
is bounded. Hence, it converges.

Comment: But we have the result that every convergence sequence is bounded but converse not trure. for e.g. take $(a_n)=(-1)^{n}$. It is bounded but not convergent.

Comment: @user375201 Yes, you are right. However, a bounded _monotone_ sequence does converge and the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-2}$ is monotone.

Comment: Yes. now its fine.

Answer (score -3):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^{2}} = \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi ^{2}}{6}$$

Where $\zeta(s)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: This does not give the OP any clue or guidance on how to prove the convergence..

Comment: It points the OP in the right direction by noting that it is a well known function and so decreases the time it would take to find more information about convergence.

Comment: @poweierstrass: with this reasoning, just point to the "Basel problem".

Comment: We have to show by definition of Cauchy sequence